# Python Flask throwing 404 URL not found

Tags: python, flask

I created a simple flask rest application with below structure

```
    flask-test
        app
         -main
            -controller
                -time_controller.py
            -service
                -time_service.py
            __init__.py
         manage.py
```

manage.py

```
from flask_script import Manager
from app.main import create_app


app = create_app()
app.app_context().push()

manager = Manager(app)

@manager.command
def run():
    app.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

time_controller.py

```
from flask import jsonify
from ..service.agg_service import get_time
from manage import app


@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def combined_result():
    time = get_time()
    return jsonify(time)
```

time_service.py

```
import time

def get_time():
    return time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
```

**init.py**

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    return app
```

When I try to run with python manage.py runserver. I keep getting 404 Not Found.(The requested URL was not found on the server.). What might be the issue?

Comment: `time_controller.py` is the only module that defines an app route, but `manage.py` does not import/use that module.

Comment: @JohnGordon, how/where to use time_controller.py in manage.py?

Comment: At the top of `time_controller`, add `from app.main import controller`.

Comment: @JakeJackson, you mean add '''from app.main import controller''' in manage.py right?, I already added it to manage.py but still getting same error.

Comment: I am looking into Blueprint concepts, but thinking it might be a overkill for this small app

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I meant at the top of `manage.py`. And I don't know what the problem is then.